# Can't compare T value1 with T value2 = default(T). Why and how to do that on C#?

Tags: c#, types, comparison

I'm trying the following:

```
T value1 = el.value; // it's of type T already
T value2 = default(T);
if (value1 != value2) // gives the following error: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
{
    // ...
}
```

So, how could I compare both values? And why do this error occur?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure T implements ICompare-ish type classes, and the method or class that defines T has those references in the declaration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either use a constraint of `where T : IEquatable<T>` as Henk mentioned, or ignore constraints and use:

```
if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value1, value2))
```

Comment: I've seen the framework use that method to test equality, seems like a good way to go, even if it is a little verbose.

Comment: I think this is the simplest way. Thanks!

Comment: @Ani: You're right. I'd forgotten there's no non-generic IEquatable interface. Will edit.

Answer (score 4):

Your surrounding generic class should list a constraint:  `T : IEquatable<T>`

And then you have to use `value1.Equals(value2)`

The reason for all this is that not all types define operator `==`

Comment: You'll get a `NullReferenceException` if `value1` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with this?

```
if (!value1.Equals(value2))
```

Should be "cross object".. :)

Comment: Personally I don't like the asymmetry of that. And of course it throws if `value1==null`

Answer (score 2):

Not all types have a default implementation of the `==` operator. For classes, the default `==` operation is to compare the references. For structs, no such default implementation exists.

You can add type constraints to generic type parameters in C#. Unfortunately, you can't define a constraint that forces the type to have an implementation of the `==` operator. The best you can do is to force the type to be a class: `where T: class`. [An article about type parameter constraints in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

if you use value1.equals(value2) then you have a problem with null values. Better:
object.equals(value1,value2)

Or for reference types (be careful):
object.referenceEquals(value1,value2)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Equals(value1, value2)
```

A good way of avoiding null ref's

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that you could do is define the comparison operator (actually, the difference operator here) to be able to compare elements of the type T. By itself, the compiler cannot really know what you mean when you write `value1 != value2`, except if the operator has been defined previously.

To define an operator, you'd use

```
public operator!=(T a, T b) {
    // Comparison code; returns true or false
}
```

Comment: I think `T` is a generic parameter, so this is probably not possible.