# How to compare <T> value with dafault<T> (C#)

Tags: c#, generics

I must find out if `T` value equals `default(T)` value.
Is there any simple to do that ?

Comment: `instance == default(T)` or `instance.Equals(default(T))`. The assumption is you override Equals or the equality operator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832192/cant-compare-t-value1-with-t-value2-defaultt-why-and-how-to-do-that-on-c

Comment: nope, operator ==, cannot be applied to operands of 'T' and 'T'

Comment: thanks everyone, it's a dub indeed